# What problems could arise in factor analysis, if I roll out my survey in small parts and do I have to perform validity theme and subtheme level both

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I am currently designing an employee engagement survey, which has 6 themes and 20 sub themes and each sub theme got atleast 4-5 questions, So I have two questions 1. Can I roll out survey theme wise for solving survey fatigue assuming that some respondents may not fill every survey so will that cause problem in factor analysis ? statistically is there a problem in that ? 2. As a part of Survey Validation do I have to perform survey validation on both theme and sub theme level ?? Because most of employee engagement survey are validated on a theme level.